# Making a POST request to an API in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, request

I've been trying to get a POST request from an API, and I'm not having that much luck in pushing it through. I'm wondering if it's because one of the parameters I'm passing is an array of objects. Been trying to get this to work for a few hours with no luck.

This post function requires two parameters, userId and classId.

//here's the api I'm calling, obviously not the actual URL

```
let apisource = www.exampleapi.com
```

//this is the class

```
let classId = 12345;
```

//these are students in the class

```
let userArray = [{
  "name": "user1",
  "userId": 101
}, {
  "name": "user2",
  "userId": 102
}]
```

I'm writing a function that takes this userArray and matches it up to a class that contains the userIds.

Here's my API call so far:

```
function getStudents(classId, userArray) {
  $.post(apisource) + "classes"), {
    userId: userArray.userId,
    classId: classId
  }, function(data, status) {
    console.log("students in class loaded)
  }
}
```

Nothing ever loads. Anyone have any suggestions or pointers for something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the DevTools of your browser to see if there's an error and if the request is sent at all? This would be important to know

Comment: The request isn't even going through. I think I'm missing something or maybe I've written something incorrectly.

Comment: Where do you call the `getStudents` function?

Comment: Oh, it's an onClick method for a button (which is contained in another file). So it should be called automatically when it gets clicked.

Comment: I think you should move the `)` after `apisource` to the end of your function

Comment: What data format are you supposed to be posting? Is it meant to be JSON?

Comment: Could you insert a `console.log` to see if the function is firing?

Comment: 1. The code has syntax errors 2. requesting something from another domain requires the URL starting with `http://` 3. it also requires support for CORS requests

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here.

For example:

```
userArray.userId
```

This part of the code is definitively invalid. Arrays have indexes, not keys like objects, for example. This means you cannot access the userId param, as you haven't defined in which index it is.

Considering your array has two items:

```
let userArray = [
  { name: 'user1', userId: 101 }, // index 0
  { name: 'user2', userId: 102 } // index 1
];
```

You would need to access the user id in the following fashion:

```
userArray[0].userId // Returns 101
userArray[1].userId // Returns 102
```

As for the request itself, it could look like something like this:

```
let apisource = www.exampleapi.com;
let classId = 12345;
$.ajax({  
   type: 'POST',
   url:  apisource,
   data: JSON.stringify({ userId: userArray[0].userId, classId: classId }),
   contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: if you're going to post JSON, you need to set the content-type

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, you cant access to **userId** property of the **userArray**, you need to pick the object first like "userArray[0].userId" or any logic to get one element.

In other hand, i recommed you to use the fetch function, is easier to use and the code look more clean with promise.

```
var apisource = 'https://example.com/';
var data = {}; // the user picked

fetch(apisource , {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: I'd move your `catch` to the end, otherwise it will transform the rejected promise into a resolved one

Comment: Not really, i agree with you moving the catch to the end, but not for that reason, the the catch will execute just when the Promise really get rejected, no matter the order. 

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: That's not correct. If the promise chain is rejected at the `fetch()` or `res.json()` stage, the `catch` will catch that rejection, log the error and then because it doesn't `throw` another error or return a rejected promise, your last `then` will execute as if everything is fine

Comment: Here's a little [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/xk0rod8t/3/) for you. Try swapping the `catch` to the end and you'll see the difference

Comment: oh you're right, this is really kinda weird behavior. But thanks for the info Phils. 
- cheers.

Comment: It's not weird if you keep in mind all `then()` and `catch()` calls return a new promise that resolves or rejects based on the callback provided

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to refactor your post implementation this way to avoid some syntax errors.

```js
function getStudents(classId, userArray) {
  $.post( apisource + "classes", { 
    userId: userArray.userId,
    classId: classId 
  })
  .done(function( data, status ) {
    console.log("students in class loaded")
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!